# Passing nested data to Django ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm wanting to know how you would pass nested data to a `ModelSerializer` if the child of the nested data is not a model on its own.

The data that I'm working with looks like this:

```
{
  'leadId': 12345,
  'updateTime': 1651250096821,
  'changeInfo': {
    'oldstage': 'New Leads',
    'newstage': 'Attempting Contact'
  }
}
```

From previous experience, I know that if I was only working with the `leadId` and the `updateTime`, my serializer would look like this:

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    leadId = serializers.IntegerField(source="lead_id")
    updateTime = serializers.IntegerField(source="update_time")

    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ["leadId", "updateTime"]
```

Which would then make it possible to do this:

```
data = {
    'leadId': 12345,
    'updateTime': 1651250096821
}
serializer = LogSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()
```

If I'm not wanting to turn `changeInfo` into its own model, is it possible to map the fields to the nested data? Something that might look like this (but this obviously doesn't work):

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    leadId = serializers.IntegerField(source="lead_id")
    updateTime = serializers.IntegerField(source="update_time")
    oldstage = serializers.IntegerField(source="oldstage")
    newstage = serializers.IntegerField(source="newstage")


    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ["leadId", "updateTime", "oldstage", "newstage]
```

Comment: Why don't use a [JsonField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield) to catch `changeInfo`, or even a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to process this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom serializer for your `changeInfo` field (you don't need to create a model for that):

```py
class ChangeInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    oldstage = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, source="old_stage") # Set max_length to a value that suits your needs
    newstage = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, source="new_stage")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass


class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    leadId = serializers.IntegerField(source="lead_id")
    updateTime = serializers.IntegerField(source="update_time")
    changeInfo = ChangeInfoSerializer(required=False) # Change to required=True if you want this field to be mandatory
    

    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ["leadId", "updateTime", "changeInfo"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        change_info = validated_data.pop('changeInfo')
        for key, value in change_info.items():
            if key == "old_stage":
                validated_data['old_stage'] = value
            elif key == "new_stage":
                validated_data['new_stage'] = value
        log = Log.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return log

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        change_info = validated_data.pop('changeInfo')
        
        instance.lead_id = validated_data.get('leadId', instance.lead_id)
        instance.update_time = validated_data.get('updateTime', instance.update_time)
        
        # Here you can use change_info['oldstage'] and change_info['newstage'] if 'changeInfo' is sent (otherwise you'll get a KeyError)
        
        instance.save()
        
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a SerializerMethodfield is a good way to go:

**serializers.py**

```py
class LogSerializer(...):

    ...
    changeInfo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_changeInfo(self, obj): return {
        "leadId" : obj.lead_id,
        "updateTime": obj.update_time
    }

    class Meta:
        fields = ["changeInfo", ...]
        ...
```